# Redirect Sub Directory Index File

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Basically I am redirecting an old category page to a new category page. The issue is the old category could be found at both `www.domain.com/category/` and `www.domain.com/category/index.shtml`.

Any links on the site point to `www.domain.com/category/index.shtml` so that's the URL I already have a redirect for in my `.htaccess`.

But there are rare cases where the `www.domain.com/category/` is being found and obviously not redirecting because it doesn't match my redirect rule.

How can I redirect both these URLs in one .htaccess line?

Essentially I'm trying to do this:

```
redirect 301 /category/ http://www.domain.com/new-category/
redirect 301 /category/index.shtml http://www.domain.com/new-category/
```

The issue being, that first rule will encapsulate everything inside of /category/, which I don't want.

And ideally I want it in one line, as there are quite a number that need to be redirected and unfortunately I can't redirectmatch them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match only if there's nothing after `/category/` or is only `index.shtml`, you can use the [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directive:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/(index.shtml)?$ http://www.domain.com/new-category/
```

Note the parts of the expression:

- `^` anchor to the beginning of the url
- `(index.shtml)` a group
- `?` quantifier, makes the previous unit - in this case the group - optional
- `$` anchor to the end of the url

Comment: But then the second rule will also catch a URL like www.domain.com/category/this-page.html - which I don't want

Comment: Awesome - exactly what I needed - just wasn't sure about the correct implementation - thanks for looking at it again! Cheers, bhtech